# Why return is not read in transactions?

Tags: node.js, transactions, sql-update, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

My code like this :

```
  public async update(params: any) {
    await Database.transaction(async (trx) => {
      const data = await Period.findOrFail(params.id, { client: trx })
      data.from = params.from
      data.to = params.to
      data.desc = params.desc

      data.useTransaction(trx)
      await data.save()

      let arrFiles = []
      for (let i in params.file_names) {
        arrFiles.push({
          fileName: Date.now() + '_' + params.file_names[i],
          fileUri: params.file_uris[i],
          createdBy: params.created_by,
        })
      }

      await period
        .related('files')
        .updateOrCreateMany(arrFiles, 'fileUrl', { client: trx })
      await File.query()
        .whereIn('id', params.removed_file_id)
        .useTransaction(trx)
        .delete()
      return { success: true }
    })
  }
```

I had `trx` in `findOrFail`, `save`, `updateOrCreateMany`,`delete`. But if I run the query it's not read `return { success: true }`

Is there something wrong with adding `trx` to the update process?

If I check on the preview tab in the console, itu return empty object, no properties. Whereas the update prosess success. I check in table of database, it success create, delete & update. Should it return `{ success: true }`

How can I solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks

Note :
I follow this reference :: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/transactions

Comment: What's the value returned?

Comment: @FirminoChangani  return empty object, no properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a void function so it does nothing.
Add a return statement will solve it.

```js
public async update(params: any) {
    return Database.transaction(async (trx) => {
        const data = await Period.findOrFail(params.id, { client: trx })
        data.from = params.from
        data.to = params.to
        data.desc = params.desc

        data.useTransaction(trx)
        await data.save()

        let arrFiles = []
        for (let i in params.file_names) {
            arrFiles.push({
                fileName: Date.now() + '_' + params.file_names[i],
                fileUri: params.file_uris[i],
                createdBy: params.created_by,
            })
        }

        await period
            .related('files')
            .updateOrCreateMany(arrFiles, 'fileUrl', { client: trx })
        await File.query()
            .whereIn('id', params.removed_file_id)
            .useTransaction(trx)
            .delete()
        return { success: true }
    })
}
```

Comment: If I put `return { success: true }` outside `await Database.transaction(async (trx) => {`, it works

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. Can you delete your answer? I want to delete this question